# Remove Rendered Text in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, render

I have some text that has been rendered on a window. When I use the screen.fill() function, the text still remains in front of the screen, so the background changes, but the text still remains uncovered.

```
#Importing Stuff
import pygame
import sys
import time
import random
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.init()

#Naming Variables
menu = 0
color = (65,105,225)
tcolor = (255,255,255)
pcolor = (255,255,255)
hcolor = (255,255,255)
width, height = 1920, 1080
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
hecolor = (255,255,255)
sys_font = pygame.font.SysFont \
           ("None", 60)

#Initializing Screen
pygame.display.set_caption("TSA Trend Game")
screen.fill(((color)))
pygame.display.update()

#Making Menu
while 1 == 1 and menu == 0:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        #More Variables
        rendered = sys_font.render \
            ("Welcome to Trends of 2016!", True, ((tcolor)))
        play = sys_font.render \
            ("Play Game", True, ((pcolor)))
        help = sys_font.render \
            ("Help", True, ((hcolor)))
        play_r = play.get_rect()
        play_r.x, play_r.y = 710, 500
        help_r = help.get_rect()
        help_r.x, help_r.y = 1170, 500
        render_r = play.get_rect()
        render_r.x, render_r.y = 710, 500
        #Display Text
        screen.blit(rendered, (710, 440))
        screen.blit(help, (1170, 500))
        screen.blit(play, (710, 500))
        pygame.display.update()
    if render_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        pcolor = (255,255,0)
    else:
        pcolor = (255,255,255)
    if help_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        hcolor = (255,255,0)
    else:
        hcolor = (255,255,255)
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and help_r.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        screen.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: instead `1 == 1` you can use `True` - `while True and menu == 0: ` but the same gives `while menu == 0:`. But you coud use `menu = True` instead of `menu = 0` and then `while menu:`

Comment: you could render text in both colors before `while` and in `while` only replace images in `blit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `while` loop, you call the `fill` function, and then you loop back up and print your text.

You should think all of your elements as being on layers. When you start your loop from the top, the order of your functions is defining what element is in front of what other element.

Usually you start by drawing the background, and then you print the individual elements (thinking with layers).

If you want to click a button, and hide the menu (which I'm guessing you're trying to do), you need to keep a memory of the state in a variable. For example have a `inMenu` which when `True` shows the text, and otherwise just shows the background. Otherwise when you go back round the loop, everything will be printed again.